# Counter inside while loop every X times increase

Tags: php, loops

I'm not really sure how to work this question, but I currently have a while loop outputting `<li></li>`.

Let's say that there are 35 rows and I want the counter to increase every five times.

So the output would be something like this.

```
 - 1 Name
 - 1 Name
 - 1 Name
 - 1 Name
 - 1 Name
 - 2 Name
 - 2 Name
 - 2 Name
 - 2 Name
 - 2 Name
 - 3 Name
 - 3 Name
 - 3 Name
 - 3 Name
 - 3 Name
 - 4 Name and so on...
```

I've tried counting throughout the loop and comparing the number to see if it was less than five and if not then increasing it, but I know that's not correct. Just can't seem to figure out the best solution.

```
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {

          $HTML .= "<li data-id='$id' data-name='$name'>$count Name</li>";              
    }
```

To try to make this clearer...basically I would like to have a counter variable running. Starting at 1, but every fifth time through the while loop, I would like to increase this count variable by one.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: does php have a modulo operator? loopno mod 5 + 1 will work for an index starting at 0.

Comment: use two counters, one that counts up to 5, and every time it hits 5, you increment the second counter.  Then include the second counter in your output...  or use one counter, and then divide it by 5 and add 1.

Comment: wow 5 answers in less than 2 minutes, granted most are wrong... but still!

Comment: It's hard to make a right answer with an unclear question

Comment: @joeframbach Sorry if it's unclear. It's tough to even explain. That's why I tried to show a sample output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$count = $rows = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($rows % 5 == 0)
        $count++;
    $rows++;
    $HTML .= "<li data-id='$id' data-name='$name'>$count Name</li>";              
}
```

Comment: Moving `$rows++;` after the if statement seems to work! Thanks

Comment: Ah, so this is what was expected. I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_fill()` (psuedo code):

```
<?php

$li = "<li>Item</li>";

$row = array_fill(0, 5, $li);

$list = array_fill(0, 35, $row);

print_r($list);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/ETCv3GBK

As in:

```
$count = 0;

while ($stmt->fetch() && $count++) {
    $HTML .= implode('', array_fill(0, 5, "<li data-id='$id' data-name='$name'>$count Name</li>"));
}
```

Another demo (ignite.io may not be working on save, though):

https://ignite.io/code/514a9bf5ec221ee821000005

Comment: This approach ignores the important `$stmt->fetch()`. It's likely each iteration will use some unique value from that db record.

Comment: Right. Well, it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++){
    $array[] = "Name " . $i;
}

$count = 1;
$output = 1;
for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
    if($count++ < 5)
        echo $output . ". " . $array[$i] . "<BR>";
    else{
        $count = 1;
        echo $output++ . ". " . $array[$i] . "<BR>";
    }
}
```

returns

> 1. Name 1
> 2. Name 2
> 3. Name 3
> 4. Name 4
> 5. Name 5
> 6. Name 6
> 7. Name 7
> 8. Name 8
> 9. Name 9
> 10. Name 10
> 11. Name 11
> 12. Name 12
> 13. Name 13
> 14. Name 14
> 15. Name 15
> 16. Name 16
> 17. Name 17
> 18. Name 18
> 19. Name 19
> 20. Name 20

Answer (score -1):

```
$i=1
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

       if($i%5==0){
          $HTML .= "<li data-id='$id' data-name='$name'>$count Name</li>";              
       }
$i++;
    }
```